# Why Laravel add back ticks with insert query

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Removing back ticks from laravel query builder with insert query.

```
$lng= 'a,b,c,d';

DB::table('table')->insert([trim($lng,'`') => $strr]);

Now this query adds back ticks automatically and i can't insert a record.

Output by this query.

insert into `table` (`a,b',c,d`) values('1','2','3','4')
```

because of these backticks i got this error message.

> **#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

How to remove these back ticks in order to insert the record properly

Comment: Take a look at [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#inserts) ==> The insert method accepts an array of column names and values !!

Comment: Oh my goodness,i am passing string values :( @Maraboc

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
DB::insert('insert into table (a, b, c, d) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', ['1', '2', '3', '4']);
```